# Can anyone else duplicate this bug concerning either Firefox or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, debugging, firefox

Okay, so this is either a jQuery problem or a Firefox problem. I'm not sure which. [I've linked to the jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tLHEF/6/) where I've been able to duplicate it both in offline testing too. Sorry about the randomness of the code in the fiddle, I've stripped down a project I'm working on to the bare essentials so I can replicate this.

**To Reproduce** (under FF 25):

1) Click in the div with a class of plaque (the grey box) and watch the table containing the number fade out with jQuery.

See it? That immediate background-color switch on the table to black before the long fade out transition? That is not how a jQuery `.fadeOut()` animation is meant to occur, and it's not documented whatsoever.

This is somehow connected to the use of the `display` property on both the `div.contents:before` and `table` elements. Right now, both are set to `display:inline-block;` - however, change either one to something that is not inline-block or inline, and the grey fade out issue disappears into thin air.

I've tried jQuery 1.9.1, 1.10.1, & 2.x; and this issue is present in all versions. I have tried the same scenario under Chrome too with no issues, which leads me to believe this is a Firefox problem. Any thoughts? Where can I go about reporting this?

Comment: I see no difference between Fx 24 and Chrome 31. I do not see a grey box, only a black box with the number 12 in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using 25.0.1 and I don't get this error. Neither Do I on any other browser so its almost certainly is a firefox problem.

**I'd check out the Mozilla Bug section and submit one there:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org**

However there really is nothing they can do, if the newer versions are fixed they'll prob just tell you to update.

Comment: Aww Geez. You're right, it's not even a Firefox problem, it's an addon problem. Restarting with addons disabled fixed it for me. Case closed, thank you! (Will accept your answer once allowed)